# order by created_at with multiple requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a little activity feed and I want to get the latest events from a few different tables:

```
@orders = Order.find :all, :limit => 5
@products = Product.find :all, :limit => 5
@links = Link.find :all, :limit => 5
```

I then want to merge them for use in my view:

```
@activity = @orders + @products + @links
```

This works, however how can I re-order them by created_at ? They are ordered by Class at the moment.

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like the general idea but for simple stuff it should work:

```
@activities.sort_by! { |a| a.created_at }
```

Comment: +1. This is the only real solution when someone keeping different types of models in a single array and wants to sort them.

Comment: Thanks! Yeh, I knew I'd be told off for this method, but I'm not sure how else to do it!